# If loops with DB Queries in Laravel Blade Templating

Tags: php, database, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create a continous system for an online magazine's website that I'm building. I want to obviously display artwork differently than I do with other pieces (say a poem or an essay), but I'm having trouble composing the loop that works with both of them. Here's the situation:

I have a `$current_genre` variable that tells me which genre is currently being read (this is all done via an admin panel). As below, the loop is supposed to identify what the current genre is and then display a certain "tile" accordingly:

```
@foreach ($pieces as $piece)
    @if ($current_genre == 'Artwork')
       <div>
          <p>Display for images</p>
       </div>                            
    @else
       <div>
          <p>Display for other items</p>
       </div>
    @endif
 @endforeach
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, as this looks fine to me. It certainly isn't the controller, because I echo the `$current_genre` variable in other places throughout the page, so I'm not sure what's going on.

EDIT for clarification: The main problem is that no matter what I do, the artwork always appears as a regular piece should, and never as I had it set under the `@if($current_genre == 'Artwork')` section

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: what's the problem you are encountering with ?

Comment: Is the current_genre a property of the $piece or are you sending it separately from the controller?

Comment: The main problem is that no matter what I do, the artwork always appears as a regular piece should, and never as I had it set under the `@if($piece->genre == 'Artwork')` section

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **genre** is the property of `$peice`, you can implement the loop as:

```
@foreach($pieces as $piece)
{
  @if($piece->genre == 'Artwork')
    ** Some Code **
  @else
    ** Some Other Code **
  @endif
}
@endforeach
```

If this does not answer your question,
you could make the question clearer by showing how you are getting the `$current_genre` variable.

Comment: `$current_genre` is just a collector that links back to a specific genre. Each genre has it's own page, so it tell me what genre will be displayed for a given page.

Comment: Can you include the code from which you are sending the $current_genre variable to the blade file.

Answer (score 0):

$current_genre is not defined how can you compare like that  @if ($current_genre == 'Artwork') you have to access the **@if ($piece->current_genre == 'Artwork')** like that. hope this will help you